# How to prevent SpringSecurity remembering Ajax urls in a Grails app

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I've had some odd issues lately where after logging in to my application,  rather than seeing the expected page, I get a json response rendered in the browser.

What's happening is I have a javascript routine on every page of the application that polls via ajax for new messages for the user.

There is a point when the user has signed out manually.. or is logged out when this ajax call is made and spring security is remembering this URL as the URL to redirect to again when logged in.  So when the user signs in again, instead of being redirected to their dashboard,  they are presented with the JSON response.

I need to prevent Spring Security from remembering Ajax called URLS,  can anyone tell me if this can be done?